# Copy/paste not working while RDP MS Remote Desktop Connection is running

Tags: remote-desktop

can anyone please help me

I can't paste anything from RDP to my desktop or from RDP to my desktop NO files No text zero

also when i close the RDP copy paste works fine like it should but when i start or run RDP even if not connecting to any remote just open the app it will somehow disable the copy paste on my computer

i cant even use copy paste in my my local desktop while RDP is running , this is insane

i tried disable clipboard and printer on RDP and enable it , none works ,

only way to get txt paste or files from remote is to install Team viewer and send files via box transfer .

any idea what to do . thank you

Answer (score 2):

On the remote computer, find the RDP Clipboard Monitor. Stop and restart it.

[image: IMG:]

On your side, make sure that you have allowed the use of the clipboard.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: The name of the executable to restart is ***rdpclip.exe***

Answer (score 2):

**>>i tried disable clipboard and printer on RDP and enable it , none works.**

Did you checked the relevant GPO of disable clipboard on the target server?

Computer Configuration --> Adminstrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Remote Desktop Session host --> Device and Resource Redirection

If the clipboard redirection used to work but failed suddenly, it is suggested to check the windows update for client and server and also manually restart **rdpclip.exe**.

1. Kill the process rdpclip.exe using the task manager in the remote computer
2. Go to RUN command and start the application rdpclip.exe

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback i did as you explained and nothing works , not sure where is the problem , sometimes the rdp clip is not working , its not even running and i can't get it to run even with commands

i tried to put it manual via startup manager app and not running on taskmanager processes its not in there

thank you for the help any other idea ?